# Js file of ckeditor failed to load in codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, ckeditor

I am trying to integrate ck editor in my admin section.i putted the ck editor folder into my assets folder.here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

after that i make a code for helper.here is the code

```
<?php
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
 * CKEditor helper for CodeIgniter
 * 
 * @author Samuel Sanchez <samuel.sanchez.work@gmail.com> - http://kromack.com/
 * @package CodeIgniter
 * @license http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/
 * @tutorial http://kromack.com/developpement-php/codeigniter/ckeditor-helper-for-codeigniter/
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/127374/
 * @version 2010-08-28
 * 
 */

/**
 * This function adds once the CKEditor's config vars
 * @author Samuel Sanchez 
 * @access private
 * @param array $data (default: array())
 * @return string
 */
function cke_initialize($data = array()) {

    $return = '';

    if(!defined('CI_CKEDITOR_HELPER_LOADED')) {

        define('CI_CKEDITOR_HELPER_LOADED', TRUE);
        $return =  '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.base_url(). $data['path'] . '/ckeditor.js"></script>';
        $return .=  "<script type=\"text/javascript\">CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '" . base_url() . $data['path'] . "/';</script>";
    } 

    return $return;

}

/**
 * This function create JavaScript instances of CKEditor
 * @author Samuel Sanchez 
 * @access private
 * @param array $data (default: array())
 * @return string
 */
function cke_create_instance($data = array()) {

    $return = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
        CKEDITOR.replace('" . $data['id'] . "', {";

            //Adding config values
            if(isset($data['config'])) {
                foreach($data['config'] as $k=>$v) {

                    // Support for extra config parameters
                    if (is_array($v)) {
                        $return .= $k . " : [";
                        $return .= config_data($v);
                        $return .= "]";

                    }
                    else {
                        $return .= $k . " : '" . $v . "'";
                    }

                    if($k !== end(array_keys($data['config']))) {
                        $return .= ",";
                    }                       
                } 
            }               

    $return .= '});</script>';  

    return $return;

}

/**
 * This function displays an instance of CKEditor inside a view
 * @author Samuel Sanchez 
 * @access public
 * @param array $data (default: array())
 * @return string
 */
function display_ckeditor($data = array())
{
    // Initialization
    $return = cke_initialize($data);

    // Creating a Ckeditor instance
    $return .= cke_create_instance($data);


    // Adding styles values
    if(isset($data['styles'])) {

        $return .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">CKEDITOR.addStylesSet( 'my_styles_" . $data['id'] . "', [";


        foreach($data['styles'] as $k=>$v) {

            $return .= "{ name : '" . $k . "', element : '" . $v['element'] . "', styles : { ";

            if(isset($v['styles'])) {
                foreach($v['styles'] as $k2=>$v2) {

                    $return .= "'" . $k2 . "' : '" . $v2 . "'";

                    if($k2 !== end(array_keys($v['styles']))) {
                         $return .= ",";
                    }
                } 
            } 

            $return .= '} }';

            if($k !== end(array_keys($data['styles']))) {
                $return .= ',';
            }           


        } 

        $return .= ']);';

        $return .= "CKEDITOR.instances['" . $data['id'] . "'].config.stylesCombo_stylesSet = 'my_styles_" . $data['id'] . "';
        </script>";     
    }   

    return $return;
}

/**
 * config_data function.
 * This function look for extra config data
 *
 * @author ronan
 * @link http://kromack.com/developpement-php/codeigniter/ckeditor-helper-for-codeigniter/comment-page-5/#comment-545
 * @access public
 * @param array $data. (default: array())
 * @return String
 */
function config_data($data = array())
{
    $return = '';
    foreach ($data as $key)
    {
        if (is_array($key)) {
            $return .= "[";
            foreach ($key as $string) {
                $return .= "'" . $string . "'";
                if ($string != end(array_values($key))) $return .= ",";
            }
            $return .= "]";
        }
        else {
            $return .= "'".$key."'";
        }
        if ($key != end(array_values($data))) $return .= ",";

    }
    return $return;
}
```

now here is my controller code:

```
public $data    =   array();

public function __construct() {

    //parent::Controller();
     parent::__construct(); 

    $this->load->helper('url'); //You should autoload this one ;)
    $this->load->helper('ckeditor');


    //Ckeditor's configuration
    $this->data['ckeditor'] = array(

        //ID of the textarea that will be replaced
        'id'    =>  'content',
        'path'  =>  base_url().'assets/admin/js/ckeditor',

        //Optionnal values
        'config' => array(
            'toolbar'   =>  "Full",     //Using the Full toolbar
            'width'     =>  "550px",    //Setting a custom width
            'height'    =>  '100px',    //Setting a custom height

        ),

        //Replacing styles from the "Styles tool"
        'styles' => array(

            //Creating a new style named "style 1"
            'style 1' => array (
                'name'      =>  'Blue Title',
                'element'   =>  'h2',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'     =>  'Blue',
                    'font-weight'   =>  'bold'
                )
            ),

            //Creating a new style named "style 2"
            'style 2' => array (
                'name'  =>  'Red Title',
                'element'   =>  'h2',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'         =>  'Red',
                    'font-weight'       =>  'bold',
                    'text-decoration'   =>  'underline'
                )
            )               
        )
    );

    $this->data['ckeditor_2'] = array(

        //ID of the textarea that will be replaced
        'id'    =>  'content_2',
        'path'  =>  'js/ckeditor',

        //Optionnal values
        'config' => array(
            'width'     =>  "550px",    //Setting a custom width
            'height'    =>  '100px',    //Setting a custom height
            'toolbar'   =>  array(  //Setting a custom toolbar
                array('Bold', 'Italic'),
                array('Underline', 'Strike', 'FontSize'),
                array('Smiley'),
                '/'
            )
        ),

        //Replacing styles from the "Styles tool"
        'styles' => array(

            //Creating a new style named "style 1"
            'style 3' => array (
                'name'      =>  'Green Title',
                'element'   =>  'h3',
                'styles' => array(
                    'color'     =>  'Green',
                    'font-weight'   =>  'bold'
                )
            )

        )
    );      


}
```

and here is my view code:

```
<textarea name="content" id="content" ><p>Example data</p></textarea>
<?php echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor); ?>
```

but my ckeditor.js is failed to load please help me or give me the suitable steps for integrating the ck editor in codeigniter.

Comment: Have you tried using full url? rather than absolute?

Comment: @VibhaJ yes i did,but failed.using my base_url() i am loading the other js files and css files and it works fine.

Comment: Why are you loading JS from the `application/views` folder? Why is that even public? I've set up ckeditor yesterday, had no problems and it worked out-of-the-box

Comment: ok meaqns i have to set up ck editor folder out side the application folder.but how could i include the path for ckeditor.php? i am currently using this path,by putting the folder in assets include_once 'http://localhost/Harshal/first_ci/assets/admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.php';

Comment: You should read about CodeIgniter more and understand how to setup the public folder, that will include your JS, CSS and images

Comment: @Vlakarados i already running successfully my js,css ,images folder for other functionalists and my templates.but for ck editor it doesn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer of my own question.
to install the ck editor in codeignitor you just have to follow the below steps:-
1.put the ck editor folder in assets(or in which you want).and give the proper path to js file.
2.now in your view section just include the js file like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/admin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

3.now on same file put this code:-

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>
```

4.now you can see the editor on your browser.